# Method "defaultAvatar" for object "Sonata\UserBundle\Twig\GlobalVariables" does not exist?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I have installed FOSUserBundle, SonataUserBundle and SonataAdminBundle

part of my kernel:

```
    $bundles = array(
    (...)
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),      
        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),

        new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
        new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),          
        new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),          

    (...)          
    );
```

I have

All is working if I disable firewall and acces Sonata admin panel while I am logged off, but if I log in to appliaction and try to access url app_dev.php/admin/dashboard error message appears:

```
Method "defaultAvatar" for object "Sonata\UserBundle\Twig\GlobalVariables" does not exist in SonataUserBundle:Admin/Core:user_block.html.twig at line 7
```

I have allready tried to clear cache and reinstall assets, but noothing has changed... Can someone help me solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved this - maybe it will help someone:

In file 'app/Resources/SonataUserBundle/views/Admin/Core/user_block.html.twig' I have changed line

```
    {% set _user_image  = app.user.profilePicture|default(asset(sonata_user.defaultAvatar)) %}
```

to:

```
    {% set _user_image  = false %}
```

You can also customise the image with another asset... but this was a very quick fix.